# Cannot execute huge sql file

Tags: sql, database-backups, heidisql

A friend of mine made a backup via HeidiSQL 4, a really outdated one. The database got deleted, and now that's my only savior. So the instead of backticks(`), HeidiSQL uses quotes(") when it comes to tables. Tried to replace all of the quotes with backticks, and executing it after, but no luck. Even tried executing the file with HeidiSQL, but that takes forever. Another friend even made a program to replace the qoutes with backticks. Any suggestions?

Comment: Double quotes are perfectly fine for table names in MySQL (you need to run in ANSI mode though - which is highly recommended anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I'd wonder what's happening with your rollback segment and transactions.

Rather than trying to process it all in one go, you might have better luck if you break it into chunks that you can commit individually.  You'll get all the data into the database, regenerate the indexes, and be back in business.

Comment: Well, this is what I've already done. I've split the 450 mb file into 5x90mb chunks and HeidiSQL4 crashed.

Comment: Don't know the details about "crashed", but perhaps even 90MB is too big.  See if you can get a 1MB chunk to work and expand.